# Script run fine in terminal, but not able to run through task scheduler

Tags: scripts

The below script run all fine it self, but not able to run with task scheduler. Please suggest.

I have tried executing the script in terminal and it runs fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Take screenshot
import -window root $HOME/screenshot.png
#Move to dropbox folder
mv $HOME/screenshot.png $HOME/$(date|tr " :" _).png
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `import` command capture some or all of an X server screen, this means that it takes actions on your screen/display, so, when you use it in a task scheduler or in a cron job or something similar, you must to set first the value of `DISPLAY` environment variable to `:0.0`. See [Graphical desktop-related variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Graphical_desktop-related_variables) for more info.

So, your script should look like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#Take screenshot
export DISPLAY=:0
import -window root $HOME/screenshot.png
#Move to dropbox folder
mv $HOME/screenshot.png $HOME/$(date|tr " :" _).png
```

Don't forget to make the script executable, using the following command:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script_name
```